# How can I easily insert hundreds of entries into a SQLite database, delimited by a specific character?

Tags: python, sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm a newbie to SQLite, so please bear with me. I have an established SQLite database that already has a single table in it which has four columns in it (first name, last name, age, location). I have a list like this that I'd like to add to the database:

```
ABC | DEF | 16 | Ontario, Canada
BCD | EFG | 17 | California, United States
CDE | FGH | 18 | London, United Kingdom
```

(And so on, for hundreds of written entries, delimited by | and saved in plain text.)

Is there an easy way to add them all to the SQLite database? Either by reading from a text file, or by just copy and pasting the entries into a text box. Maybe through the SQL console itself, or a Python or Node.js script, or something else that's easy to install on the PC or run in a browser. It's just local for a project. Thanks!!

Comment: Most database systems have a way to "dump" a table as a `CREATE TABLE` query and a series of `INSERT`s.  Those commands can be fed directly into the SQLite command line tool, with (almost) no processing necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `executemany` against a sequence of parameters, in this case a function that yields your text file row by row.

```
def iter_data():
    with open("some_file.txt", "r") as fin:
        for row in fin:
            yield row.split("|")


con = sqlite3.connect("some_db")
query = """
INSERT INTO my_table(first_name, last_name, age, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
"""

with con:
    conn.executemany(query, iter_data())

con.close()
```

You can read more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany). You will probably need to include proper error handling, type coercion, etc.. but hopefully you understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

yes actually there are some online tools that do that
first you need to convert it to csv format , which in your case is just to changing the delimiter and giving it a header and use tools

like https://konbert.com/convert/csv/to/sqlite

or this java tool :https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-csv-to-sqlite-online

Comment: Is there any way not to use the comma delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for NodeJS and Sqlite:

```
var inputFileName='input.txt';
var dbName='sample.db';


var fs = require('fs');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbName);
var input = fs.readFileSync(inputFileName);


//creates the table
function createDB(){
  db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(attr1 VARCHAR(64), attr2 VARCHAR(64), attr3 VARCHAR(64), attr4 VARCHAR(64))`);
}

//insert a single line
function insertSingleRow(param1, param2, param3, param4){
  var stmt=db.prepare(`INSERT INTO mytable(attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`);
  stmt.run(param1, param2, param3, param4);
  stmt.finalize();
  console.log("Row inserted");
}

//select and print all record from the table
function sqlSelect(){
  db.all("SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4 FROM mytable", function(err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(function (row) {
      console.log(row.attr1, row.attr2, row.attr3, row.attr4);
    })
    });
}

//parses the input file and inserts all line into the table
function parseFileAndInsert(){
  var lines=input.toString().split("\n");
  for(i in lines){
    if(i<lines.length-1){
      var inputValues=lines[i].split("|");
      insertSingleRow(inputValues[0], inputValues[1], inputValues[2], inputValues[3]);
    }
  }
}

//executes the table creation, parsing of the file
db.serialize(function() {
  createDB();
  parseFileAndInsert();

  // for evaluation
  // sqlSelect();
});
```